# Python Type Error "<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'

Tags: python

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

#Import Data set

dataset= pd.read_csv('Data.csv') 
X = dataset.iloc[:,:-1].values
Y = dataset.iloc[:,3].values

#X[:,1:3].astype(str)

#Taking Care of The Missing Data
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer

imputer = Imputer(missing_values=np.nan,strategy='mean',axis=0)
imputer = imputer.fit(X[:,1:3])

X[:,1:3] = imputer.transform(X[:,1:3])

#Taking care of Categorical data
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
labelencoder_X = LabelEncoder()
X[:,0]= labelencoder_X.fit_transform(X[:,0])

#OneHot for Dummy Variables
onehotencoder= OneHotEncoder(categorical_features=[0])
X= onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()


labelencoder_Y = LabelEncoder()
Y= labelencoder_X.fit_transform(Y)

#Split data into Train and test
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2, 
random_state=0)
```

I was following this tutorial series where the instructor didnt have an error but i do, its in the last line, The error says Type Error "<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'. Please help.[image]

Answer (score -1):

Fixed my issue. The data in the csv file was changed, hence causing the error.